# how to populate database using procedures

Tags: sql, database, oracle, entity-relationship, create-table

I have about 15 different Tables filled with different data and different entity relationships.

I need to create a script which will populate my database with the content of those tables.

After script is finished, i run it in cmd, using sqlplus and later START *path to file*

i have two different sql files, one named db_spec.sql and another db_body.sql.

In my db_body.sql i've created a procedure to store data from two tables which have 1:N relationship.

**First table**

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
ID_LOCATION INTEGER NOT NULL,
LOCATION_NAME VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
POSTCODE INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE LOCATION
ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_LOCATION PRIMARY KEY (ID_LOCATION));
```

**Second table**

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS (
ID_ADDRESS INTEGER NOT NULL,
STREET VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
HOUSE_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
FK_ID_LOCATION INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ADDRESS
ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_ADRESS PRIMARY KEY (ID_ADRESS));

ALTER TABLE ADRESS
ADD (CONSTRAINT FK_ADRESS_ID_LOCATION FOREIGN KEY
(FK_ID_LOCATION) REFERENCES LOCATION(ID_LOCATION));
```

Now i need to populate them using data. Let's say

LOCATION_NAME = "London"
POSTOCDE = "394505" ...and so on

I've created this script, but as i run it, nothing shows up, so there's obviously some error in it.

**db_spec.sql script**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE apartment AS
PROCEDURE fill_location(location_number NUMBER);
PROCEDURE fill_address(number_of_addresses NUMBER);
END apartment;
```

**db_body.sql script**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET LINESIZE 400
SET TIMING ON
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY address AS
PROCEDURE fill_location(location_number NUMBER) IS
    p_location_name VARCHAR2(20);
    p_postcode NUMBER (10,2);
BEGIN
    FOR num IN 1..location_number LOOP
        p_location_name := 'Location';
        p_postcode := dbms_random.value(1000,9600);
        p_postcode := p_postcode ||' '|| TO_CHAR(num);
        INSERT INTO LOCATION (ID_LOCATION, LOCATION, POSTCODE)
        VALUES (num, p_location_name, p_postcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(num);
    END LOOP;
END fill_location;

PROCEDURE fill_address(number_of_adresses NUMBER)IS
    p_street_name VARCHAR(20);
    p_house_number NUMBER (10,2);
    p_id_address NUMBER(10);

    CURSOR data IS
        SELECT ID_LOCATION
        FROM LOCATION;
BEGIN
    FOR num_loop IN data LOOP
        FOR num IN 1..number_of_adresses LOOP
        p_street_name := 'Ulica';
        p_house_number := dbms_random.value(1,99);
        p_street_name := p_street_name ||' '|| TO_CHAR(num);
        SELECT NVL(MAX(p_id_address)+1,1)
        INTO p_id_address
        FROM ADDRESS;
        INSERT INTO ADDRESS (ID_ADDRESS, FK_ID_LOCATION, STREET, HOUSE_NUMBER)
        VALUES (p_id_address, num_loop.ID_LOCATION, p_street_name, p_house_number);
        dbms_output.put_line(num_loop.ID_LOCATION);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;           
END fill_address;
END;
SHOW ERRORS;
```

**Can you guys please help me fix the problem so the code will run and work fine? Any input is appreciated!**

Btw **oprema_stanovanja.polni_kraj = address.fill_location**

[image: Nothing happens]

Comment: are you missing a COMMIT?

Comment: @StevieG im running the code in the cmd using sqlplus. nothing happens. can you please check edited post.

Comment: you say `oprema_stanovanja.polni_kraj = address.fill_location`. Shouldn't that be `apartment.fill_location` instead of `address.fill_location` ? If this is a typo, did you check if the LOCATION table populated after running the procedure? What were you expecting?

Comment: I have it right, i just wrote it wrong here. How can i check the data in the table? Sorry it's my first time working with this :(

Comment: @fox You would need to fix the package first before executing it. See my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing it... `COMMIT;`
Based on the screenshot you issued, add a `/` to the end of your body and procedure definitions.

Comment: im running the code in the cmd using sqlplus. nothing happens. can you please check edited post.

Comment: Place `show errors` at the end of those when you compile them.

Comment: it doesnt show any errows. im not sure those nums on left in cmd (5,6,7,8) mean anything good in this case. im not sure it even goes trough scripts.

Comment: Can you show us why/how you think there isn't any data in the `LOCATION` table? Also execute a `select * from v$sql where sql_text like '%INSERT INTO LOCATION%';` and upload those results?

Comment: Please elaborate on why `COMMIT;` would help and where in the code it should be inserted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: nothing happens, just the numbers keep getting bigger. How can i even check the data in database with cmd

Comment: @Ben, not too sure if that is a legitimate question or not.

Comment: @gipinani, without a commit statement how would the transaction be finished? Sure his session would see the changes but we aren't even sure how he is seeing if the data isn't in there.

Comment: @fox, `select count(*) from LOCATION;` that will tell you how many records are in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the package posted doesn't compile without errors.

You would need to fix the following first:

1. Terminate `FOR LOOP` statements with `END LOOP`
2. Terminate `BEGIN` of procedures with `END <procedure_name_here>`
3. PL/SQL variable names need to be different than the actual column name to avoid ambiguity in the INSERT statement. [ You can't have `LOCATION` the column name and PL/SQL variable with the same name. Oracle cannot resolve which is to be used where in the INSERT]

To get you started, I have fixed the `fill_location` procedure below. Proceed similarly for the other procedure.

```
create or replace package body apartment as
procedure fill_location(location_number number) is
p_location_name varchar2(20);
p_postcode number(10,2);
begin 
    for num in 1.. location_number loop
        p_location_name := 'location';
        p_postcode := dbms_random.value(1000,9600);
        p_location_name := p_location_name ||' '|| to_char(num);
        insert into location (id_location, location_name, postcode)
            values (num, p_location_name, p_postcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(num);
    end loop;
end fill_location;
```

Fix the above errors/suggestions until you get 'PL/SQL successfully compiled`. If you get 'compiled with errors' use "show errors" to find and fix any other errors.

Comment: thank you i will try this and ill come back with the results in few mins

Comment: i tried running it in sqldeveloper and this is what i get..."line 2: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set LINESIZE 400
PACKAGE BODY oprema_stanovanja compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning
Elapsed: 00:00:00.010"

Comment: @fox Do you get any errors with "show errors" ? Please update your post with the fixed code. Is the `LOCATION` table getting populated now?

Comment: hey again. i updated my code. Actually the first part is easy one as the relation is 1...the second one where the relation is N is harder to solve. Still get the errors, but it doesnt show any of them...

BTW...the **cursor** part is a must, as it is teachers instructions. Can you please check 2nd part of code and help me fix it? Thank you very much

Comment: @fox If you see my example answer, I have already shown how to fix [2] also. You need to use `end fill_location;` to end the procedure `fill_location`. You need to use `show errors` command to actually see the errors. If that is not working in SQL developer, use SQL*Plus. Once the errors are displayed, read, understand them and make amend to your code.

Comment: im sorry i totally did not see this one...i fixed it now, but sql developer still says **"Warning: execution completed with warning"**

Comment: @fox: That means there are still errors in your code. What `show errors` says?

Comment: @fox: Try `View --> Log` in SQL Developer to see the errors in SQL developer. If that doesn't work out, then execute this SQL and share your result: `select * from dba_errors where name in ('ADDRESS','APARTMENT');` where ADDRESS and APARTMENT are the name of your packages. I don't know which is correct as you seem to keep changing them.

Comment: @fox: I see the `END;` for your package is missing. This needs to be fixed along with any other errors you might find.

Comment: You can already see "Log" the link above i sent you, and there's nothing in it. If i run your last code, it says **table or view doesn't exist"**

Comment: @fox The error message precisely tells you what has gone wrong. You haven't created the tables that you are inserting to, you need to create them.

Comment: i think it's meant "dba_errors" doesnt exist. i have created and altered all the tables. still says the warning...i dont even know if thats error or just warning. but if i want to display data, there's nothing in the tables.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the contents `TEXT` column in `DBA_ERRORS`. Looks like you do not have access to DBA_* views. Did you try `SHOW ERRORS` in SQL*plus after compiling the package? Also did you add an `END;` statement at the last as I suggested? Please post latest code with the fixes.

Comment: yeah i did put end there. and yes i did try to show errors but no magic here either...code updated btw. maybe its simple an error in inser or values statement

Comment: even if i only try to fill table location with the data in code 1, and try to display data later...it's empty. i dont know what the hell is that, but i just can't make it work. Even simple code such as above isn't working...